# Rewrite index.html (default) but not index.php .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I didn't quite find what I need despite I'm sure it is asked before..

I need to rewrite index.html to a subdirectory but allow index.php to be visited.
I have a Wordpress installe in the root, but as long it is in dev I would like it to be visited if addressed directly with exact path and all visitors writing the domain only to be redirected. Thought and tried todo this with .htaccess

```
Redirect /index.html http://www.example.com/home
```

But this redirects also index.php to the subdirectory.
I also tried adding

```
remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

To the functions.php

What next?

Comment: Redirect is not rewrite - even it should actually work, so I suspect there might be another reason for unexpected redirect. However, is there a reason that you are not using RewriteRule instead Redirect? RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://www.example.com/home should solve your problem. If it still mess with index.php then it should be something else in your app.

Comment: It did not quite work. it rewrites to error page
"The requested URL /example.comi/home was not found on this server."

Comment: Use it with http:// SO didn't let me and trimmed that part. I put with space now. RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http:// www.example.com/home

Comment: it rewrites to correct sub but it still rewrites everything else too. so for eg index.php. But if I add wp-login.php it goes actually there. I cannot see front end however. They all get rewrited to subdirectory

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code at root `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)       /home/$1 [L,R=302]
```

the above code will redirect any request to /home/ directory including main domain and excluded only the index.php

for example if request site.com/page  it will go to site.com/home/page

if you request site.com it will direct you to site.com/home/

but if you request site.com/index.php  it will go to site.com/index.php

Comment: Ok I will try. But 
        [code] RewriteRule ^       /index.php [L,R=302]
         # the line above will redirect any index or index.php to index.php
Does not sound like what I am looking for

Comment: try it as it is and let me know , make sure that you empty browser cache

Comment: It does not work as I wanted. if I just write the domain/URL without file name a blank page turns up. Same with index.php and all wordpress pages.
If I put index.html there too it redirects til example.com/home/ as expected

Comment: cache emptied. did not help

Comment: so you need to rediect every index.html to spacific directory or not ? or you means only if any one request /dorectory/index.php to be /directory/ ?

Comment: if someone writes in the address field in the browser
www.example.com then this person gets redirected to www.example.com/home/

then if someone give the exact path www.example.com/index.php this index.php opens up.
 Please remember I have a Wordpress installed. index.php is wordpress mainfile

Comment: do you have index.html as well ? in root?